# Different Linear Regression Coefficients with statsmodels and sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels

I was planning to use sklearn linear_model to plot a graph of linear regression result, and statsmodels.api to get a detail summary of the learning result. However, the two packages produce very different results on the same input.

For example, the constant term from sklearn is 7.8e-14, but the constant term from statsmodels is 48.6. (I added a column of 1's in x for constant term when using both methods) My code for both methods are succint:

```
# Use statsmodels linear regression to get a result (summary) for the model.
def reg_statsmodels(y, x):
    results = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()
    return results

# Use sklearn linear regression to compute the coefficients for the prediction.
def reg_sklearn(y, x):
    lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    lr.fit(x, y)
    return lr.coef_
```

The input is too complicated to post here. Is it possible that a singular input x caused this problem?

By making a 3-d plot using PCA, it seems that the sklearn result is not a good approximation. What are some explanations? I still want to make a visualization, so it will be very helpful to fix the issues in the sklearn linear regression implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that

```
I added a column of 1's in x for constant term when using both methods
```

But the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression) of LinearRegression says that

```
LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True, [...])
```

it fits an intercept by default. This could explain why you have the differences in the constant term.

Now for the other coefficients, differences can occur when two of the variables are highly correlated. Let's consider the most extreme case where two of your columns are identical. Then reducing the coefficient in front of any of the two can be compensated by increasing the other. This is the first thing I'd check.