# Why `sklearn` and `statsmodels` implementation of OLS regression give different R^2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels

Accidentally I have noticed, that OLS models implemented by `sklearn` and `statsmodels` yield different values of R^2 when not fitting intercept. Otherwise they seems to work fine. The following code yields:

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import statsmodels
import sklearn.linear_model as sl
import statsmodels.api as sm

np.random.seed(42)

N=1000
X = np.random.normal(loc=1, size=(N, 1))
Y = 2 * X.flatten() + 4 + np.random.normal(size=N)

sklernIntercept=sl.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True).fit(X, Y)
sklernNoIntercept=sl.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False).fit(X, Y)
statsmodelsIntercept = sm.OLS(Y, sm.add_constant(X))
statsmodelsNoIntercept = sm.OLS(Y, X)

print(sklernIntercept.score(X, Y), statsmodelsIntercept.fit().rsquared)
print(sklernNoIntercept.score(X, Y), statsmodelsNoIntercept.fit().rsquared)

print(sklearn.__version__, statsmodels.__version__)
```

prints:

```
0.78741906105 0.78741906105
-0.950825182861 0.783154483028
0.19.1 0.8.0
```

Where the difference comes from?

The question differs from [Different Linear Regression Coefficients with statsmodels and sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38451508/different-linear-regression-coefficients-with-statsmodels-and-sklearn) as there `sklearn.linear_model.LinearModel` (with intercept) was fit for X prepared as for `statsmodels.api.OLS`.

The question differs from
[Statsmodels: Calculate fitted values and R squared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851787/statsmodels-calculate-fitted-values-and-r-squared)
as it addresses difference between two Python packages (`statsmodels` and `scikit-learn`) while linked question is about `statsmodels` and common R^2 definition. They are both answered by the same answer, however that issue has been arleady discussed here: [Does the same answer imply that the questions should be closed as duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate)

Comment: What do you mean? -0.72... is quite different from 0.78...

Comment: Always seed random data for reproducibility: `np.random.seed(###)`.

Comment: The absence of an intercept changes the definition of R2 in statsmodels. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664471/why-would-r-squared-decrease-when-i-add-an-exogenous-variable-in-ols-using-pytho/29665662#29665662 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851787/statsmodels-calculate-fitted-values-and-r-squared/24852415#24852415

Comment: @Parfait agreed. In this particular case I omited seed, as the sample is quite large and results differ every single run. However for the sake of correctness I have updated the example.

Comment: @user333700 May you give that as an answer? I would like to accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Statsmodels: Calculate fitted values and R squared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851787/statsmodels-calculate-fitted-values-and-r-squared)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by @user333700 in comments, OLS definition of R^2 is different in `statsmodels`' implementation than in `scikit-learn`'s.

From [documentation of `RegressionResults` class](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults) (emphasis mine):

> rsquared
>
> > R-squared of a model with an intercept. This is defined here as 1 -
> >     ssr/centered_tss if the constant is included in the model and **1 -
> >     ssr/uncentered_tss if the constant is omitted**.

From [documentation of `LinearRegression.score()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score):

> score(X, y, sample_weight=None)
>
> > Returns the coefficient of
> >     determination R^2 of the prediction.
> >
> > The coefficient R^2 is defined as (1 - u/v), where u is the residual
> >
> > sum of squares ((y_true - y_pred) ** 2).sum() and v is the total sum
> >     of squares ((y_true - y_true.mean()) ** 2).sum(). The best possible
> >     score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model can be
> >     arbitrarily worse). A constant model that always predicts the expected
> >     value of y, disregarding the input features, would get a R^2 score of
> >     0.0.